# Passport local strategy auth seems to only work on localhost with a shared MongoDB instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

This is a weird one, but I'm not sure what else could be going on. I've successfully deployed the [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) strategy for a Node.js Express app with user accounts stored in MongoDB. I'm using Mongo as a service via MongoLab.

My accounts and login auth works as expected locally. But when I deploy my app to AWS (using the same Mongo service still), the same account credentials fail. I'm wondering... is Passport somehow using the URL, port, or other environment-specific information to authenticate users? Perhaps in how password lookup is performed?

I've narrowed it down to the `passport.authenticate('local')` middleware, although it would surprise me if this library somehow performed differently in different environments with the exact same code.

I should also mention that I'm using the `passport-local-mongoose` plugin for my User model.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Seems that in different environment the auth only works on the environment it was created on.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I figured this out.

On my local system, I had a newer version of node, but on my deployed version (on AWS ElasticBeanstalk) it was using v0.10.36.

If you look at the code for `passport-local-mongoose` you'll see this:

```
var pbkdf2DigestSupport = semver.gte(process.version, '0.12.0');
...
var pbkdf2 = function(password, salt, callback) {
  if (pbkdf2DigestSupport) {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, options.iterations, options.keylen, options.digestAlgorithm, callback);
  } else {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, options.iterations, options.keylen, callback);
  }
};
```

So if the two different versions of node has one above 0.12.0 and one below, you are going to get different crypto functionality.