# passport-local (-mongoose) in deployed website error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I developed a website on my machine, and it works fine when I run it locally. I am using ExpressJS and Passport for authentication. Mongoose for the DB.

I have a package called `passport-local-mongoose` which works fine, it simplifies handling user logins and registrations.

Back-end (ExpressJS)

```
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

app.use(session({
    secret: "I dunno, a secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session());
```

When I deployed the website to heroku, the authentication doesn't work. But it works fine on `localhost`.

Login route:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.login(user, (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    })
})
```

I believe this is because of the package `passport-local-mongoose`, the name of the package implies that it works *locally* only.

How can I transition from `passport-local-mongoose` to a package that works on the live website? What package(s) can I use to achieve this? Am I right in saying `passport-local-mongoose` only works locally?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080488/passport-local-strategy-auth-seems-to-only-work-on-localhost-with-a-shared-mongo) question but it doesn't seem to answer my problem.

NB: I can't include the code for my whole website as there is too much code.

Comment: Could you show us the whole route? I've never seen `passport.authenticate` inside the `req.login` callback before.

Comment: @jasonandmonte added code to question

Answer (score 1):

To clarify `passport-local-mongoose` should work locally or when deployed to a server. The term local is how the passport ecosystem describes systems that use a username and password.

Based on your route, you shouldn't need to make a call to `req.login` as `passport.authenticate()` middleware invokes `req.login()` automatically.

Reference: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/

Its difficult to tell what the root cause of the issue is, but I would recommend refactoring the route to see if that resolves your issue.

```js
app.post('/login',
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  })

  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I refactored the route and tested it locally, but the login stopped working